# Ruby 2.2.0 installed and not installed at the same time

Tags: ruby

When I open a middleman folder I get this message:

```
ruby-2.2.0 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-2.2.0'
```

the command doesn't do anything but

```
rbenv install 2.2.0
>> rbenv: /Users/kristoffer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0 already exists
```

What's going on?

Comment: Look at your settings for rbenv to make sure that the paths are correct in your environment.  Why you are getting rvm messages, I don't know.  But it points to ruby not being in your path, or the correct version at least.  To be clear, the command (whatever that command is, as you don't show it) obviously does something.  It reports the message that ruby-2.2.0 is not installed.

Comment: What happens if you run - rvm install ruby-2.2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question mentions both RVM and rbenv, which makes me think that at some point you've installed both. Since they solve pretty much the same task, it makes sense to leave one and drop the other.

So, here's what I suggest:

1. Make a backup :)
2. Completely drop `/Users/kristoffer/.rbenv` and `/Users/kristoffer/.rvm` (note that all the gem files and Rubies you've installed are going to get deleted, so be sure not to keep anything important of yours in those folders).
3. Eradicate all the traces of both RVM and rbenv in your environment (e.g. `.bashrc` file).
4. Do a clean install of either RVM or rbenv. I personally choose the former, but that's probably just a matter of taste.

Hope this helps!